# Create a grid in WPF with a FrameworkElementFactory

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

in short in am making out static `XAML` description UI into a dynamically created one. Here is the `XAML` code that I want to replicate in c#:

```
<GridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <CheckBox Grid.Column="0"
                      Margin="4,0,5,0"
                      VerticalAlignment="Center"
                      IsChecked="{Binding Path=DataContext.AreAllSelected,
                                          RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView},
                                          Mode=OneWay}"
                      Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.ChangeAllSourcesSelection,
                                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       UI:DisplayedObjectProperties.DisplayedObject="{Binding}" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</GridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>
```

And here is what I have come up with:

```
GridViewColumn col = new GridViewColumn();

DataTemplate template = new DataTemplate();

FrameworkElementFactory gridFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Grid));
FrameworkElementFactory col1 = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(ColumnDefinition));
FrameworkElementFactory col2 = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(ColumnDefinition));

col1.SetValue(ColumnDefinition.WidthProperty, new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto));
col2.SetValue(ColumnDefinition.WidthProperty, new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star));
gridFactory.AppendChild(col1);
gridFactory.AppendChild(col2);

FrameworkElementFactory boxFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(CheckBox));
boxFactory.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 1);
boxFactory.SetValue(FrameworkElement.VerticalAlignmentProperty, VerticalAlignment.Center);
FrameworkElementFactory tBlockFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
tBlockFactory.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 2);
tBlockFactory.SetValue(FrameworkElement.VerticalAlignmentProperty, VerticalAlignment.Center);
tBlockFactory.SetValue(TextBlock.TextProperty, LanguageManager.Parse(columnVM.ColumnName));

gridFactory.AppendChild(boxFactory);
gridFactory.AppendChild(tBlockFactory);
template.VisualTree = gridFactory;

col.HeaderTemplate = template;
```

However this does not give me the desired effect as both the CheckBox and the TextBlock seem to be in the same column. How do I assign each to the respective column? As you can see I've done some strange appendings, because I have no Idea what I'm doing.

[Here is the result I want:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7RJ0a.png)

Comment: Shouldn't you replace 1 and 2 by 0 and 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set the `Grid.Column` attached property of the `TextBlock` to 1:

```
tBlockFactory.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 1);
```

There is no reason to set the property for `boxFactory` since it should have the default value of 0.